# django rest framework post - Invalid drive specification

Tags: django, curl, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to post an XML to my API and although it works fine from the URL if I try to CURL the XML file in I get an "Invalid drive specification" error.

This is my CURL command -

```
curl -X POST -d 5022_4qa.xml http://servername:9001/deploy/calendar/&format=xml
```

As soon as I try the curl I get back a few errors before it fails.  My assumption is that it's not grabbing the XML file for some reason.  I can even put the full path of the file the error is the same.

```
....
</div>{
    &quot;evntmst_type&quot;: [
        &quot;This field is required.&quot;
    ],
    &quot;evntmst_id&quot;: [
        &quot;This field is required.&quot;
    ],
    &quot;evntmst_name&quot;: [
        &quot;This field is required.&quot;
    ]
}</pre>
....

Invalid drive specification
```

In the return on the API side it's returning a 400 code.

Answer (score 1):

To post the contents of a file with curl, you need to prefix the file name with @. So:

```
curl -X POST -d @5022_4qa.xml http...
```

Comment: nope doing that gives the same Invalid drive specification

Comment: I gave up trying to figure out curl I'm using urllib2 and that works fine.